# How can I 'know' where I am clicking in a D3 tree with several label per nodes

Tags: javascript, d3.js, svg

I'm making an orgchart with D3 tree. In each node I have several ID. I'd like to click on my ID and get this ID in a pop-up. So far I can get ALL the node's IDs when I click on ONE ID of the node.
To be precise, I use a JSON where ALL my IDs are sotred, and the way I display ALL my node's IDs is :

```
.on('click', function () {
    window.alert(d.data.id);
})
```

So I suppose I need an X variable to know on what ID I'm clicking and display with :

```
.on('click', function () {
    window.alert(d.data.id[X]);
})
```

The Question is, how can I get this X, OR is there a better way to achieve that (I dont't really know js)

I'm really stuck on this, thank you for reading.

EDIT : I add more of my code for clarity :

```
    nodeEnter.append('text').each(function (d) {
    var j = 0;
    while (d.data.id[j] && d.data.id[j] != "") {
        d3.select(this)
            .style("fill", "black")
            .style("text-anchor", "middle")
            .attr('cursor', 'pointer')
            .on('click', function () {
                alert(d.data.id[j]);
            })
            .append('tspan')
            .text(d.data.id[j])
            .append('tspan')
            .text(d.data.label[j]);
            j++;
    }
})
```

id is an array of ID in the JSON. Each node contain an array of id. So I need to bound "j" and the things I write (id and label).

Comment: don't use `while(cond) { ...; j++;}` Use a `for` loop. Do not add the click handler to the `text` but to the `tspan` elements, then you can get the `text()` of the clicked element.

Comment: Your question is about the data, so how is the json data looks like that you used for binding? i.e. If you have `.data(json)` somewhere in your code, what it is looks like?

Answer (score 0):

There is a better way

Add hidden HTML field to each node and on click find that field and get its value

```
.on('click', function () {
    alert($(this).find("[type=hidden]").val());
})
```

Comment: I tried this (maybe the wrong way) but it listed all the IDs of the node. In answer you say "Add hidden HTML field to each node" BUT I have severals IDs in ONE node. So adding a hidden value to each ID leads to same result.